# What ssl certificates do i need for my redirect url to securely get the access token?

Tags: android, uber-api

primary error: 3 certificate: Issued to: CN=policyplan.in;
                                                                               Issued by: CN=policyplan.in;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the info where to buy a valid SSL certificate please check this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404907/where-could-i-buy-a-valid-ssl-certificate).
Process is described bellow:

- Step 1: Host with a dedicated IP address. In order to provide the best security, SSL certificates require your website to have its own dedicated IP address. ...
- Step 2: Buy a Certificate. ...
- Step 3: Activate the certificate. ...
- Step 4: Install the certificate. ...
- Step 5: Update your site to use HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100%ly sure what you're asking for...

If you just want to bypass the certificates to check the website you can use a library like [Fast Android networking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking). Its configuration can be used to allow special certificates or just accept all certificates (trust all).